# Where can I find my last successful build?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I created an application that worked, then I started changing it and now it won't run. I'm given the option to run "the last successful build" instead of my current one, which I use and it works fine, where can I access this last build?

Comment: In the bin/Debug folder of your project, if you are compiling a Debug version. Otherwise bin/Release

Comment: Instead of looking for the last successful build have you considered using a [`Version Control`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) for your source code? This would have allowed you to access not only the last successful build but absolutely any build that you might have ever produced. If you haven't, well then, you definitely should for your next project to avoid those kind of awkward situations.

Comment: Hmya, the default VS settings are not that friendly to a new programmer.  Or an old one, I don't like them either.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Change "On Run, when projects are out of date" to Always Build.  Change "On Run, when build or deployment errors occur" to Do Not Launch.  You'll now stop looking for the ghost in the machine.